# How to save a created html file to a specific location by giving a path

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I have created a html file of my results using .to_html() function.By default the html file saves to the root location of your project folder.But what if i want to save it to the specific location?How to give a path to the created folder .Im using flask to connect python to html.

Comment: Do show the code you currently have and it will be much easier to provide you a good answer

Answer (score 0):

You can access the root path of the `flask` through `app.root_path`.

So let's say your folder name is `myHtmlFiles`. So we can save the files like below:

`file.save(os.path.join(app.root_path, "myHtmlFiles", "hey.html"))`

You can also take a look at [app.config](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/), you can put your folder path here and use it anywhere in the aplplication.

Comment: thankyou Ejaz,but when im using "file.save" function its giving me this error"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'".Do i have to import something to use this function